# When a dataset Retrieves data?

Tags: c#, dataset

I want to know when a dataset tries to retrieve data.I don't Know if it works after each update of the records or whenever it is needed from the code.
any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: DataSets don't retrieve data. They are data containers. It is the DataAdapter that fills a dataset when you call the Fill method

Comment: I need several datasets in my app, doesn't it make the app heavy and slow?@Steve

Comment: It depends on how much data you retrieve from your storage. It has nothing to do with the dataset object per se, but on how you write your program and display your data to your users.

Comment: @steve thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you could add system output lines to any application by using: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("<message>");` anywhere in your c# files.

These output lines could be thrown in areas that query a database, return a successful query, or even call on information provided by the query to populate user interface fields.

Another helpful method is to use [breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) in visual studios.  With breakpoints, you can step through your code line by line.  If you put a break point in an area where you query a database, the code will stop at that point and you can evaluate if your query successfully connected, if you have the correct information, or the proper syntax to pull the data out of the returned query.